# Modify onclick attribute on field condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a form that goes something like this:

```html
<form action="#" class="header_form clearfix">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Address" id="autocomplete">
<a href="#" class="btn" onclick="document.location='/address?address='+$('#autocomplete').val();return false;">Enter Your Address</a>
</form>
```

I want to place a Javascript condition to check if the text input has text in it before the button would have the onclick parameters. If it has no text on keyup, the onclick is not on button. How to do so?

Comment: Why do it this way? Just attach a click handler to the button using `addEventListener`. When you listener is triggered, check to see if the text input has text, and respond appropriately.

Comment: @RayNicholus how to do so? can you include a code how to do so? -newb here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var email = $.trim( $('#autocomplete').val() );
  if(email.length) {
    window.location = '/address?address='+email;
  } else {
    alert('Enter your email first');
  }
});
```

$.trim is there to at least prevent empty spaces triggering a valid submit.
In any case you'd better go with an *EMAIL* regex pattern: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score -1):

This will disable the link if its not a valid email address too

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
      }

      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#autocomplete').bind('input', function() { 
          if ($(this).val().trim().length === 0) {
            document.getElementById('myButton').removeAttribute('href');
          } else {
            if (validateEmail(document.getElementById("autocomplete").value) === true) {
              document.getElementById('myButton').setAttribute("href",'/address?address=' + document.getElementById("autocomplete").value);
            } else {
              document.getElementById('myButton').removeAttribute('href');
            }
          }
        });
        document.getElementById('myButton').removeAttribute('href');
      });
    </script>

    <form action="#" class="header_form clearfix">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Address" id="autocomplete" />
      <a href="#" id="myButton" name="myButton" class="btn">Enter Your Address</a>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The question says "before the button would have the onclick parameters" which I assume is to disable the click itself if the input doesn't have a valid email address. Can the smart As give a reason and then downvote instead of going at the downvote button like a mad bull?